# For Each Loop Causing Excel to Hang

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

I'm having trouble with a For Each loop causing Excel to hang. Everything works in the code below until I get to the `For Each C In ColRng` code. Once removed, everything works again.

```
Sub CopyWB()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim C As Range
Dim MemAnal, AttAnal As Variant
Dim ColRng As Range

Set MemAnal = Worksheets("Membership Analysis")
Set AttAnal = Worksheets("Attendance Analysis")

MemAnal.Select
    Set ColRng = Range(MemAnal.Cells(1, 1), MemAnal.Cells(1, MemAnal.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
    Range("E:J").EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("E1:J1").Value = Array("Site Status", "Org Service Unit", "Org Region", _
        "Location State", "Key State", "DOD")
    For Each C In ColRng
        If InStr(1, C.Text, "Total Member Count using Age Group for YTD") = 0 Then
            GoTo Break
        Else
            C.EntireColumn.Insert
            C.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Teens " & Left(C.Text, 4)
        End If
Break:
    Next C  

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you do your `If` statement like that? If I'm reading it correctly, you could do `If Instr([that formula])<> 0 Then // C.EntireColumn.Insert //C.Offset(0,-1).Value = ...` and therefore not have to use a `GoTo` (which is best practice to avoid).  Also, do you want to check each cell in that entire range? From A1 to say AZ1?  It's likely hanging because you're checking a lot of individual cells.

Comment: If you find a cell with that text you insert a column before it, which means the next loop will process that cell again, and again, and again, etc.

Comment: @BruceWayne My `If` statement was formatted as you suggested previously, but the issue was still there. This was just my latest iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Rory for pointing out what was causing an issue as far as the logic goes. I've rewritten to avoid that logic. Below is the updated code:

```
Sub CopyWB()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim C, ColRng, pyAddress, cyAddress As Range
Dim MemAnal, AttAnal As Variant

Set MemAnal = Worksheets("Membership Analysis")
Set AttAnal = Worksheets("Attendance Analysis")

MemAnal.Select
    Range("E:J").EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("E1:J1").Value = Array("Site Status", "Org Service Unit", "Org Region", _ 
        "Location State", "Key State", "DOD")
    Set ColRng = Range(MemAnal.Cells(1, 1), MemAnal.Cells(1, _ 
        MemAnal.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
    Set pyAddress = ColRng.Find("Total Member Count using Age Group for YTD", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set cyAddress = ColRng.FindNext(pyAddress)
    pyAddress.EntireColumn.Insert
    pyAddress.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Teens " & Right(pyAddress.Text, 4)
    cyAddress.EntireColumn.Insert
    cyAddress.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Teens " & Right(cyAddress.Text, 4)    

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

It should be noted that this works for me because I happen to know that in this data, I will only ever have two instances of this text but the location of those instances constantly changes thus the need for the `.Find` function. I was just overthinking how I went about it initially.